# Visual Studio Code Insider switch remote to local

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I open Visual Studio Code Insider it tries to connect to my remote server and also even if its not connected (since the VM is off) and I try to save a new file it tries to save it on the server. I'm having a hard time saving a file locally or even opening a local project into VS Code. I also don't want VS Codee to automatically connect to remote server.

I'm using Visual Studio Code Insider 1.35 and the [remote development extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144170/ubuntu-16-04-cannot-install-vs-code-remote/1144177#1144177) by Microsoft.

Comment: The only thing I found working for this was to create a new workspaces for your local system and your remote one. And then work with Several VS code instances/windows open.

Comment: @veritaS how do we create different workspace for local and remote?

Comment: The Insiders release is prerelease software. Have you submitted this issue on the support Github?